# Datagrid not loading the form

Tags: vb.net

[Here is the screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUWIk.png)
Public Class Form3

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CustomerRecordsDataSet.CustomerRecords' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.CustomerRecordsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CustomerRecordsDataSet.CustomerRecords)
End Sub
```

First of all I'm just a newbie with `VB`. I tried searching for tuts and tried to use the `datagrid`. I created my `MS Access` document for the database and created the form so I linked the `datagrid` form to my main window but whenever I click the button for the `datagrid` form it shows **InvalidOperationException was unhandled** and it highlights this `Me.CustomerRecordsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CustomerRecordsDataSet.CustomerRecords)`.
Need an ASAP explanation thanks in-advance

Comment: Did you look at the detail for the exception?

Comment: I added a screenshot mind if you can look into it.

Comment: In future, when there's an error message that tells you exactly what the problem is, please pass it on to us.  That information is intended to help diagnose the issue and if you want us to do the diagnosing then logic dictates that you provide us with that information.

Comment: sorry my fault i didnt actually read into it.And Thanks for the response,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you what the problem is. The data provider isn't there (Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0). This can happen if you don't have it installed, or you are running an "Any CPU" or "x64" application on a x64 system. Have you tried the ACE provider (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0)?

Details: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

There are also many articles on that site that address various problems. For example: [Jet for Access, Excel and Txt on 64 bit systems](https://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/)

> The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet and the Jet ODBC driver are available in 32-bit versions only. You can't run them in 64 bit mode.

Comment: thanks for the response. it worked, and sorry for a noob question hahaa

Comment: You're welcome! Everyone is a newbie at some point, so no worries. :-)